# Facebook Insights Timezone

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Confused with insights data, if I read this it says all data is in Pacific  time, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/. But, when I fetch data for  page_fans life time using graph api

> /insights/page_fans/lifetime?

I get the values as

> {
>            "value": 190453, 
>             "end_time": "2013-10-30T07:00:00+0000"
>           },

which suggests the time is in GMT, what should I consider?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't sound like time is in GMT. It is giving you a timezone in GMT but the date it gives you corresponds to midnight in PST (PDT?) on 2013-10-29.